# Error on persistence.xml configuring HSQLDB with Hibernate

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, jboss7.x, hsqldb

I am configuring one HSQLDB database inside the application folder, follow below the persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="crmUnity" transaction-type="JTA">

<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>


      <class>br.com.crm.model.entities.Cliente</class>
      <class>br.com.crm.model.entities.Contato</class>
      <properties>  
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>  
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>  
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />  
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />  

        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file://database/crm;shutdown=true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.user" value="sa" />
        <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO" />

      </properties>  
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The JBOSS 7.1.3 while starting show the error on log:

> 18:40:10,477 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 170) HHH000319: Could not get database metadata: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:hsqldb:file://database/crm;shutdown=true

Can anybody help me about configure the jdbc url to resolve this error?

Thank's, Tarcísio.

Comment: It appears a issue related to missing jars.. Can you check the necessary driver/connector jars for HSQL db in your lib folder.

Comment: the jars exists on classpath. I performed tests using basic jdbc connection and worked fine. Using Hibernate doesn't work yet. I am trying with assumption that the connection url is wrong due to error message that pointed to his line,  but the message too said "No suitable drive found". @viraj